# Is the amplitude proportional to frequency in electromagnetic waves?

Tags: special-relativity, doppler-effect

In Einstein's 1905 [paper](http://hermes.ffn.ub.es/luisnavarro/nuevo_maletin/Einstein_1905_relativity.pdf), under the section: **§ 7. Theory of Doppler’s Principle and of Aberration**

Einstein derived the relativistic Doppler effect:

$$f'=f\dfrac{1-\cos\phi \cdot \dfrac{v}{c}}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$

He then directly stated that:

$$A'^2=A^2\dfrac{\left(1-\cos\phi \cdot\dfrac{v}{c}\right)^2}{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}$$. Where $A'$ and $A$ are the amplitudes of the waves in two frames in relative motion.

I can't understand where does the relation $A \propto f$ come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that there is a slight error in your equation. In Einstein's paper (on page 16), it is the square of the amplitude that is written:
$$A'^2 = A^2 \frac{\left(1 - \cos \frac{\phi v}{c}\right)^2}{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}$$
So the proportionality relation is:
$$A \propto f$$

Also, we should be careful with the definitions. The amplitude that is mentionned is that of the electric field. The electric field is just part of a larger tensor (the field strength tensor) and therefore can have unusual properties.

Perhaps more explicitly, the invariant amplitude is the amplitude of the quadripotential. Let's write it $(\phi,\vec{A})$. It's amplitude $\sqrt{\phi^2 - \vec{A}^2}$ is constant and does not depend on the relative velocity of the emitter.

But the electric field is:
$$\vec{E} = - \vec{\nabla}\phi - \frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t}$$
The derivative gets an $f$ factor out explaining the proportionality behaviour.

On a more theoretical note, this is to be expected on (Minkowskian) symmetry grounds. Indeed, all this behaviour can be inferred from the transformation properties under boosts. The quadripotential is a 4-vector and therefore, its norm behaves as a scalar under transformation. The electric field however is part of an antisymmetric rank two tensor (the field strength) and is therefore a pseudo-vector. Its norm behaves as the time component of a vector which explains the additional factor.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you elaborate mathematically how the derivative gives a factor of $f$?

Comment: Consider a plane wave, for instance (complex notation):
$$\phi = \phi_0 \exp\left(\mathrm{i}(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x} - \omega t\right)$$
and similarly:
$$\vec{A} = \vec{A}_0 \exp\left(\mathrm{i}(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x} - \omega t\right)$$
where $\omega = \frac{f}{2\pi}$ and $k$ is given by the dispersion relation: $\omega = kc$.

The electric field is:
$$\vec{E} = -\vec{\nabla}\phi -\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t}$$
$$\vec{E} = -\mathrm{i}\vec{k}\phi + \mathrm{i}\omega\vec{A}$$
where $\vec{k}$ and $\omega$ are both proportional to $f$ giving the conclusion.

Comment: exuse me but I'm not following your argument. Your last equation implies that $E$ is proportional to $f$. What this has to do with the amplitude of electric/magnetic wave being prop. to $f$?

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question then.
But to me, an electric/magnetic wave is a wave in the electric/magnetic fields. The amplitude of the wave is the amplitude of the field. The norm of the eletric field (or magnetic field - it doesn't matter for plane waves) in complex notation is precisely the amplitude of the eletric wave.
Maybe this formulation will be less troublesome: $E$ proportial to $f$ means that its norm is proportional to $f$, which is precisely the amplitude of the "electric force" as stated in Einstein's paper (page 16).

Comment: what do $\phi$ and $\vec{A}$ represent?

Comment: Ok. I've used a more modern treatment with the quadri-potentiel $(\phi,\vec{A})$. $\phi$ is the electric potentiel and $\vec{A}$ is the vector potential for the magnetic field.

I've read in a bit more details the derivation made by Einstein. He didn't use the potential (hardly surprising at that time) but instead used the transformation rule derived on page 14.

All he did was to compute (Einstein's notation):
$$X'^2 + Y'^2 + Z'^2 = (X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2)\frac{\left(1−cos \phi vc\right)^2}{1−\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$$
in the case of a plane-wave. But he clearly skips it ^^.